# Why does my table always begin on a new page even though there is enough space on the previous page

Tags: tables, floats

So after exporting my tables from excel. Each time I try inputting them in, they all begin on a new page and the text after them also begin on a new page so below is sample of the document and the attached image

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{coursework.bib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}%hidelinks enables link hiding
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{float}
\UseRawInputEncoding


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\section{Results} 
The result for the solar radiation for every hour using the solar time on the selected day which is January 15th is shown in table \ref{tab:Jan}. The respective KT and surface albedo values were used as displayed in table \ref{tab:JosKT}.

\include{Jan}

The calculated results for a tilt angle of $17^{o}$ is shown in table \ref{tab:ALL}
\include{All}

Also, the results obtained when the tilt angle is $0^{o}$ is shown in table 
\include{zero}





\end{document}
```

An example of the code for the tables is shown below. bear with me its quite a long table, i want to be sure I have not missed anything

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'All'
\begin{table}[H]
  \caption{Solar radiation at $0^{o}$ tilt angle}
  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrrrrr||r||}
    \toprule
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .878,  .706}       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{January}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{February}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{March}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{April}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{May}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{June}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{July}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{August}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{September}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{October}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{November}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{December}} \\
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .878,  .706} \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Hour}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Wh/m\^2} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Wh/m2} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Wh/m2} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Wh/m2} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Wh/m2} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Wh/m2} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Wh/m2} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Wh/m2} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Wh/m2} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Wh/m2} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Wh/m2} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Wh/m2} \\
    \midrule
    \midrule
    1.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} \\
    2.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} \\
    3.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} \\
    4.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} \\
    5.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} \\
    6.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{3.96} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{6.19} & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} \\
    7.00  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{90.67} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{103.36} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{141.96} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{176.88} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{185.38} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{169.20} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{139.12} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{123.37} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{135.92} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{151.14} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{151.20}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{112.42}} \\
    8.00  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{307.01} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{323.47} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{356.61} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{369.96} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{357.02} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{323.90} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{277.47} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{257.55} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{289.67} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{331.34} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{365.49}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{326.33}} \\
    9.00  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{498.40} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{519.08} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{546.52} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{539.43} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{507.20} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{459.74} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{399.50} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{375.71} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{423.92} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{487.42} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{551.20}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{513.54}} \\
    10.00 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{651.81} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{676.84} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{698.75} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{673.74} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{625.66} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{567.46} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{496.90} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{469.82} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{529.52} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{608.74} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{695.66}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{661.30}} \\
    11.00 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{756.78} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{786.00} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{802.94} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{763.74} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{704.35} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{639.72} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{563.02} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{533.44} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{599.26} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{687.03} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{789.05}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{759.52}} \\
    12.00 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{806.15} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{839.12} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{851.97} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{803.29} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{737.89} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{671.59} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{593.36} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{562.25} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{628.40} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{716.95} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{824.98}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{801.53}} \\
    13.00 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{796.57} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{832.59} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{842.51} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{789.70} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{724.01} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{660.92} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{585.85} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{554.29} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{614.96} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{696.47} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{801.01}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{784.45}} \\
    14.00 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{728.69} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{766.85} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{775.20} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{723.90} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{663.64} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{608.41} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{541.01} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{510.09} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{559.84} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{626.98} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{718.78}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{709.45}} \\
    15.00 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{607.12} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{646.38} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{654.63} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{610.36} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{560.91} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{517.65} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{461.89} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{432.67} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{466.80} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{513.21} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{583.89}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{581.64}} \\
    16.00 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{440.16} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{479.39} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{489.02} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{456.83} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{422.81} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{394.83} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{353.89} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{327.30} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{342.19} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{362.93} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{405.54}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{409.73}} \\
    17.00 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{239.19} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{277.25} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{289.64} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{273.78} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{258.76} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{248.32} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{224.35} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{201.16} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{194.49} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{186.36} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{195.86}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{205.44}} \\
    18.00 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{17.89} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{53.75} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{70.10} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{73.66} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{79.93} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{88.10} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{82.12} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{62.86} & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .937,  .808}\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .38,  0}{33.78} & 0.00  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} \\
    19.00 & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} \\
    20.00 & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} \\
    21.00 & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} \\
    22.00 & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} \\
    23.00 & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} \\
    24.00 & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & 0.00  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{0.00} \\
    \midrule
    \midrule
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .878,  .706} \multicolumn{1}{p{8.93em}}{\textbf{Total (Wh/m2/day)}} & 5940.44 & 6304.08 & 6519.83 & 6255.28 & 5831.52 & 5356.03 & 4718.48 & 4410.51 & 4818.75 & 5368.57 & \multicolumn{1}{r}{6082.67} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{5865.35} \\
    \midrule
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .878,  .706} \multicolumn{1}{p{8.93em}}{\textbf{Total (KWh/m2/day)}} & 5.9404 & 6.30408 & 6.51983 & 6.255279 & 5.83152 & 5.35603 & 4.71848 & 4.4105 & 4.8188 & 5.36857 & \multicolumn{1}{r}{6.0826694} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{5.865345} \\
    \midrule
    \rowcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .878,  .706} \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{KWh/m2/month}} & 184.15 & 182.818 & 202.115 & 187.6584 & 180.777 & 160.681 & 146.273 & 136.73 & 144.56 & 166.426 & \multicolumn{1}{r}{182.48008} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{181.8257} \\
    \midrule
    \midrule
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .776,  .878,  .706}\textbf{2056.5} \\
\cmidrule{13-13}    \end{tabular}%
}
  \label{tab:0}%
\end{table}%
```

Below is the result

[image: The result gotten when the code is run]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx.

Comment: The `\include` command always starts on a new page.  It's not obvious to me, though, why the text following the table should go to a new page; even though `table` is a float, there is clearly enough space left on the page to accommodate a single sentence.

Comment: (in case you aren't aware) `\input` is like `\include`, but it won't start a new page.  That is the limit of my ability to help on this question.

Comment: The [H] doesn't allow the table to float.